# "Когда" — союз или союзное слово?

Tags: союзы, части-речи

В данном отрывке "когда" — это союз или союзное слово?

> Мой первый друг, мой друг бесценный!
>   И 
>   я судьбу благословил,
>   Когда мой двор
>   уединенный,
>   Печальным снегом
>   занесенный,
>   Твой колокольчик огласил.

Я считаю, что это союз.

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вы абсолютно правы.

```
Когда является союзом
```

— в придаточном времени (Отец мой скончался, когда мне был шестнадцатый год. Лесков);

— в придаточном условия (Когда нужно чёрта, так и ступай к чёрту! Гоголь).

```
Когда является союзным словом
```

— в придаточном времени, если в главной части есть указательное слово тогда (Отец мой скончался тогда, когда мне был шестнадцатый год);

— в придаточном изъяснительном (Я знаю, когда он вернётся);

— в придаточном определительном (Тот день, когда мы встретились впервые, я не забуду никогда; когда в определительном придаточном можно заменить основным для этого придаточного союзным словом который, ср.: Тот день, в который мы встретились впервые, я не забуду никогда).